# Custom: My Printer

Tags: android, printing, bluetooth, thermal-printer

[This is the link of the Bluetooth mobile printer i used for Printing](http://www.custom.biz/pos-printers/my-printer-13-5)

> Does anyone here tried it implementing it in the Android Application? I already using it right now but im having problem with the Printing font Sizes.

Here's my code from the SDK.

```
//Fill class: LEFT X2
            fntPrinterX2NormalLeft.setCharHeight(PrinterFont.FONT_SIZE_X1);                 //Height x1
            fntPrinterX2NormalLeft.setCharWidth(PrinterFont.FONT_SIZE_X1);                  //Width x1
            fntPrinterX2NormalLeft.setEmphasized(false);                                        //No Bold
            fntPrinterX2NormalLeft.setItalic(false);                                            //No Italic
            fntPrinterX2NormalLeft.setUnderline(false);                                     //No Underline
            fntPrinterX2NormalLeft.setJustification(PrinterFont.FONT_JUSTIFICATION_LEFT);   
            fntPrinterX2NormalLeft.setInternationalCharSet(PrinterFont.FONT_CS_DEFAULT);        //Default International Chars
```

The PrinterFont.FONT_SIZE_X1 is large as the default and the maximum size is up to FONT_SIZE_X8.
Could anyone tell me the limit of the size of printing, or this size was the default?
Is there anyone here from the Custom Printer?

Their SDK has lack of information.. Not like Bixolon Printer It's detailed and Informative..